# why not these 4 li s stand next to each other

Tags: html, css

my #slides is 800px and each li is 200px wide, so why 4 lis does not fit in one row?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y2eJ/)

```
<div class="carousel-container">
    <div class="slides">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>some html</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>some html</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>some html</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>some html</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because there is space in the width of one space character between them – because the white space between their closing and opening tags gets condensed to that. http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the fiddle. But for future sake, it's helpful to post the relevant css here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant say I know the answer but changing

```
display: inline-block;
```

to

```
float:left;
```

Will accomplish the desired result ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y2eJ/6/))

**UPDATE**

As CBro said (and he deserved full credit, should he post an answer), condense the spaces between `</li>` and `<li>` ([fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y2eJ/9/))

Answer (score 0):

You can also eliminate the whitespace between the `li`s by removing the closing `</li>` tags.  They are optional anyway.